Auto sized bracketing with Math Operators
I noticed that $$\exp(\frac12), \exp\{\frac12\}, \exp[\frac12]$$ are all (at least visually) equivalent to $$\exp\left(\frac12\right), \exp\left\{\frac12\right\}, \exp\left[\frac12\right]$$
The same is also true for \sin, \cos, \log and \ln. How do I declare my own math operators that follow this convention?
Here is a MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\[
\exp{\frac{-1}{2}} \quad \exp(\frac{-1}{2}) \quad \exp[\frac{-1}2]
\]
\end{document}

Commenting the import of the physics package reverts the behaviour back to normal.
Edit: This behavior happens when using the physics package.

How are these visually equivalent? The first versions have normal brackets, while the second versions have auto-scaled ones. And off-topic: you should really avoid $$...$$, but use \[...\] or other environments instead.

@Gargantuar Oh I'm sorry I forgot to mention, this is using the physics package. Also yeah, I always use align* environment, it's just more natural to write $$ on stackexchange since I use math stack a lot haha

I'd strongly advise against using physics. The syntax introduced by it is bewildering at best.

@Skillmon do you have any alternative solution? As in how can I achieve this behavior without physics package

you should fix your question to have an example of the problem since the behaviour you are asking about is a feature of a package you don't mention in the question and don't use in the code. It's best to always make code examples complete small documents.

as shown in Gargantaur's answer the physics package is forcing over-sized \left\right parens on \sin,  it woul dbe better to fix that rather than use the same style on new operators

@DavidCarlisle, I've added a MWE. Is there a way to perfectly automate the size of the brackets within the framework of my question? I know people prefer manually sized brackets but right now, I value automation a lot more.

I'd remove physics and then use \left(...\right) if you want automatic sizing. The sizing isn't always perfect but it's OK and I don't see how physics is helping here. Or (better) declare paired delimiters using \DeclarePairedDelimiter from amsmath/mathtools

@Anvit "this behavior" is exactly what I categorize as "bewildering at best". I'd go with \DeclarePairedDelimiter. Too much automation and flexible syntax often enough leads to undetected malformattings in the output.

@DavidCarlisle, as mentioned in the question, the physics package helps because it allows me to use whatever brackets I want and auto size them as well without having to type \left etc. I think physics2 does that as well if you prefer that over physics
@Skillmon what you categorize as "bewildering at best" may not be that huge of a deal for me. If you really think it's horrible thing to do, give me an example why rather than just saying it's bad. I way I edit my documents is naturally different that what you do, there's no need to say what I'm doing is factually wrong.

@Anvit Although my solution is exactly what you want, I have to agree with DavidCarlisle and Skillmon. In TeX typography, math should be very intentional; there's probably a reason for why Knuth didn't autoscale brackets by default. Try \[ \left( \sum_{j=0}{n} j \right) \] vs. \[ \biggl( \sum_{j=0}{n} j \biggr) \]: imho, the second looks better.

@Gargantuar I completely agree with you, but at same time I also see that these sort of examples are rare. Most of the time, I'm happy with just \left. If any such cases arise, I can manually size brackets at that time. It's sort of like saying that "I don't want to use cruise control driving at all because it's not perfect." The only reason I haven't accepted your answer yet is because people do not like physics package, which is reasonable. I'm looking into physics2, I feel like that has something.

@Anvit physics2 explcitly states in its documentation for physics users, §2.3, that it doesn't plan to implement this feature you requested. The recommended way is to type e.g. \[ \sin \ab( \frac{1}{2} ) \] after loading \usephysicsmodule{ab}.

Looking at the style file of physics, you can do the following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}
\DeclareMathOperator{\hey}{hey}
\NewDocumentCommand{\h}{}{\trigbraces{\hey}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sin(\frac{1}{2})
    \h(\frac{1}{2})
\]

\end{document}



Can't I do the same thing with physics2 as well? Something like \newcommand{\myexp}{\exp\ab}

@Anvit Yeah, you can, but there are a multitude of caveats. 1. \myexp must be followed by one of (, [, \{, \langle, \lvert, \lVert and finished with the appropriate closing delimiter. 2. Hence, something like \myexp(() will throw an error. 3. Hence, \myexp \alpha is impossible. 4. Hence, $\myexp$ will throw an error. Note that all of this isn't a problem if you're fine with using two different commands for the exponential function.

while I do see that the documentation says that is not allowed, surprisingly 3. and 4. do not throw any error in a very simply document. Maybe they will in a more complex document. Thanks for taking out the time to answer my questions, your kindness is appreciated.

You might use \DeclarePairedDelimiters from mathtools.  One of the examples in the manual is
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

This creates the following commands:

A command like \abs{x}, which produces non-scaling vertical bars
A command like \abs*{\frac{a}{b}}, which automatically scales the delimiters with \left and \right
An optional size argument, such as \abs[Bigg]{\frac{a}{b}}, which chooses a specific size


I wanted the function to work with whatever brackets I choose, not just the specific one we declare in the definition.
